# How can I remove status code 201 and keep 200 status code along with other status codes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

For PUT method in spring controller if I want to show 200 status code along with other status codes like 401,404 and remove the 201 status code .

I tried using @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) but that is not working for me.

```
@PutMapping("/entry/user").  
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK).          
public UpdatingVO userEntry(

UpdatingVO update = new UpdatingVO();  
try{.  
update=service.allowUser(updateDtsVO);   
}
catch(Exception e){.   
update.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());   
update.setStatus(UserConstant.FAILURE).  
}
return update;
```

Comment: This question needs more context. What have you tried so far? Please provide more details so that we can understand enough to help help you.

Comment: I have added what I have tried so far . I tried using @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you can define in the same controller a return status in case of a particular exception and use ResponseEntity to return 2xx. Take this example:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}") 
public ResponseEntity<?> updateOrCreate(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Entity entity) {
    boolean created = dao.updateOrCreate(entity);
    if (created) return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("entities/" + id)).build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}


@GetMapping("/{id}") 
public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
    Entity entity = dao.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(entity);
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
static class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
static class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Custom exception:

```
class UpdatingException extends RuntimeException {

private UpdatingVO update;

public UpdatingException(UpdatingVO up) {
    this.update = up;
}

public UpdatingVO getUpdatingVO() {..}

}
```

Handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(UpdatingException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public UpdatingVO handleUpdating(UpdatingException ex) {
  return ex.getUpdatingVO();
}
```

In case of use the handler you need to throw the ex in the userEntry method like `throw new UpdatingException(update);`

Comment: Is there any other way than using responseEntity? I have added what I have tried so far.

Comment: I tried using ResponseEntity but it is not removing status code 201

Comment: You can create your own exceptions and handle them in your controller. I updated my example.

Comment: @PutMapping("/entry/user").  
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK).          
public ResponseEntity<UpdatingVO> userEntry(

UpdatingVO update = new UpdatingVO();  
try{.  
update=service.allowUser(updateDtsVO);   
}
catch(Exception e){.   
update.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());   
update.setStatus(UserConstant.FAILURE).  
}
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(update);

Comment: I am getting 200 status response for this method.But I am also getting 201 status  code in responses in the swagger .Creating the exception handler will just give me required status code but it will not remove the 201 code in response section of swagger.